# Autofill iOS12 alert message user to save password after login to the app first time?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, autofill, ios12

I'm implementing autoFill to my iOS app using this tutorial ["iOS 12 Password Tools: Improving User Security and Experience"](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7162-ios-12-password-tools-improving-user-security-and-experience) everything work fine but the iOS is not prompt me with UIAlert to save the password when I login for the first time. I want to ask how I can trigger the UIAlert to prompt the user to save the password to keychain first time?

[image]

Comment: Have you set up associated domains in your app's capabilities and also set up a valid `apple-app-site-association` file on your server? That site you reference is useful but also see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/

Comment: I did that but still, I am not able to trigger the UI alert to save the username password for the app. I know you can use safari to add it but as round trip but not a lot of our users are that technical

Comment: Hi @NinjaDeveloper, I have faced the same issue. Did you solve this? Please share your solution.

Comment: I followed the tutorial step by step

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper i am trying to implement saving my credentials to key chain and reterview via  autofill. But save password pop up doesn't show up...Can u please help me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389979/save-username-and-password-in-key-chain-and-use-that-as-autofill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to clear the text fields and remove the view for View hierarchy.

Note: with Xcode 10 you can use save the username password in the simulator.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    view.endEditing(true)

    txtfEmail.text =  nil
    txtfPassword.text = nil
}
```

Comment: I think the second line should be `super.viewDidDisappear(animated)`