# Save Password Alert does not appear in Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, passwords, credentials, associated-domains

I want this alert to appear when the user logs in to my application.

[image]

I made this tutorial for this. [iOS 12 Password Tools: Improving User Security and Experience](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7162-ios-12-password-tools-improving-user-security-and-experience)

Also I have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831632/autofill-ios12-alert-message-user-to-save-password-after-login-to-the-app-first) topic. And using this code in my LoginViewController.swift in viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear. But This alert does not appear at all.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if user.id != 0 {
        usernameTextField.text = nil
        passwordTextField.text = nil
    }

}
```

My **entitlements** file like this (Suppose that **twitter.com** is the website of my application):

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:twitter.com</string>
    <string>webcredentials:twitter.com</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.authentication-services.autofill-credential-provider</key>
<true/>
```

And off course my *usernameTextField* content type is **username** and *passwordTextField* content type is **password**.

So I want to ask why this alert didn't come off.

Comment: May be the save password functionality are disabled in your device (You can check it in Settings->Genral->All Password of device)

Comment: It is enabled. I tried 2 devices this. Also can save password with Safari.

Comment: Post code used for display alert.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a new account or changing the password, use the .newPassword text content type for the password TextField:

```
newPasswordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
confirmPasswordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
```

[Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)

---

You can also manage iCloud Keychain Credentials using the Security.SecSharedCredentials API. It will still require a domain association (entitlements):

```
SecAddSharedWebCredential("your_domain.com" as CFString,
                           usernameTextField.text as CFString,
                           newPasswordTextField?.text as CFString, {(error) in })
```

[SecAddSharedWebCredential](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1617986-secaddsharedwebcredential)

---

Next, you should add the Apple App Site Association file to your website.

Create a file named apple-app-site-association (without an extension). Update the file to contain the JSON representation of a dictionary listing the app identifiers associated with your domain for the webcredentials service.

```
{
   "webcredentials": {
       "apps": [    "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.DemoApp",
                    "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.DemoAdminApp" ]
    }
}
```

Use the following format for the app identifiers:

```
<Team Identifier>.<Bundle Identifier>
```

Place this file either in your site’s .well-known directory, or directly in its root directory. If you use the .well-known directory, the file’s URL should match the following format:

```
https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

You must host the file using https:// with a valid certificate and without using any redirects.

[Setting Up an App’s Associated Domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains)

Answer (score 0):

After the autofill password feature is implemented, the save password alert will show on you **push** or **present (full screen)** to the next `ViewController`.